# How to Implement Attach More Files in MVC and jquery for FileUploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In a post Yahoo, when attaching files, there is a button "Attach more files" when you press it, it becomes one field to insert the file. 
Here is the code:

```
<a href = "javascript: addUploadFields ();" id = "attach_more"> Attach more files </ a>
```

How can i implement it MVC?

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-file-upload-plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tyring many unsuccessful solution I got it from

```
http://lbrtdotnet.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/asp-net-mvc-multiple-file-uploads-using-uploadify-and-jqueryui-progressbar/
```

[click this useful link](http://lbrtdotnet.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/asp-net-mvc-multiple-file-uploads-using-uploadify-and-jqueryui-progressbar/)

```
 I kept the Url Values in a session



 public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (Session["myAL"] == null)
        {
            al = new ArrayList();
        }
        else
            al = (ArrayList)Session["myAL"];

        var uploadFile = file;

            if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"),
                                                   Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));                    
                al.Add(filePath);
                Session["myAL"] = al;
                uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }

        var percentage = default(float);

        if (_totalCount > 0)
        {
            _uploadCount += 1;
            percentage = (_uploadCount / _totalCount) * 100;
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            Percentage = percentage
        });
    }
```

and then retrieved them in my Post Create Action

```
public ActionResult MultimediaCreate(MultimediaModel newMultimedia)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.submitMultimedia(newMultimedia);
            al = (ArrayList)Session["myAL"];
            foreach(string am in al)
            {
                MarjaaEntities me = new MarjaaEntities();
                MultimediaFile file = new MultimediaFile();
                file.MultmediaId = newMultimedia.id;
                file.MultimediaFileUrl = am;
                me.MultimediaFiles.AddObject(file);
                me.SaveChanges();
                Session.Remove("myAL");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("MultimediaIndex");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For uploading multiple files using File Upload control i use JQuery Multifile plugin which is simple and easy to see. See this link [JQuery Multiple File Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

Just inlcude this library and JQuery and its syntax is like

```
<input type="file" class="multi"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Controller and Action that allows you to upload files
2. Find a client side plugin that achieves uploading multiple files. One that I've found to work quite well is the Upload plugin by [Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/index.html)

If you go with Kendo UI, this should get you started:

- http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/upload/overview

**Controller:**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase[] files) {
        // The Name of the Upload component is "attachments"
        foreach (var file in files) {
            //Do Something
        }
        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

**View**

```
<form action="/Controller/Action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" />
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is almost same question like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575787/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575787/how-to-upload-image-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-ajax-or-any-other-technique-without-p/14576326#14576326) . Plug in support multi file upload. Do let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many file uploader such as

[this](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

and u can use this code for upload
this code is client side:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
```

First you can do some validation if you want. For example in the onChange event of the file.

```
    $(':file').change(function(){
        var file = this.files[0];
        name = file.name;
        size = file.size;
        type = file.type;
        //your validation
    });

$(':button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: completeHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

and this is your contoller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase[] files) {
        // The Name of the Upload component is "attachments"
        foreach (var file in files) {
            //Do Something
        }
        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

so if you dont want use ajax use this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}
<h2>
    Upload</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Upload", controllerName: "User", 
                       method: FormMethod.Post,
                       htmlAttributes: new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <text>Upload a photo:</text> <input type="file" name="files"  multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```